# operator[] overloading and constantness

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

In my code I created two template functions overlading the [] operator (an excercise to build my version of STL map):

```
const V& operator[](const K& key) const;    // X = map["kuku"]

V& operator[](const K& key);                // map["kuku"] = x
```

I then use the operator through the following function:

```
invokeStkCmd (my_stacks[stk_name], my_cmds[crnt_word]);
```

whose template is

```
invokeStkCmd (StackComp* stkPtr, const shake_cmds_t cmd)
```

This invocation uses the `V& operator[](const K& key)` template (at least for the second parameter) which can add an entry to the map and not the other template as I intended. Referring to a recent operator overloading post here at Stack Overflow, it seems my opertaor overloading template functions are OK. Do I need to do something in my invokeStkCmd function or are my operator overloading functions not accurate after all?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when dealing with objects whose behaviour differs largely when they are to be modified. It is caused by the simple fact that the overload is resolved based on solely argument types, not by the return type or use of the return value. So the easiest solution is using a `const_cast` to make the map object `const` just before the indexing takes place:

```
invokeStkCmd (my_stacks[stk_name], const_cast<my_map<Whatever> const&>(my_cmds)[crnt_word]);
```

This might not satisfy you because of its verbosity and error-proneness; in this case there is also an advanced way exploiting the fact that cast operator overloads are resolved based on their return type, differing from ordinary functions. I have posted an answer like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440749/51831). Note that it is pretty hard to do it right.

Comment: That's a `static_cast`, not a `const_cast`. A `const_cast` is used almost exclusively in ill-formed programs.

Comment: @KerrekSB: `static_cast` could be used to perform that too; I chose `const_cast` in this in this case, because it says more clearly that the conversion is only about changing constness - and in this case, where we cast from a const to a nonconst, that *can't* be wrong. Morever, a [`const_cast` will prevent you from inadvertently making a copy by omitting the `&`](http://ideone.com/v43rN).

Comment: @KerrekSB: To your second point, what is an ill-formed program is defined by the standard - and using `const_cast` has nothing to do with it. If you thought simply "wrong programs", I disagree - there are legitimate uses for it.

Comment: Hi @jpalecek, many thanks I adopted the simpler option with the cast and not the proxy but mentioning it does open up tha mind ...